# Sitecore publishend event, get the item from event args

Tags: c#, sitecore

Here is the code I tried, same code worked for me on item saving event.

```
 public void OnPublishEnd(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    SitecoreEventArgs eventArgs = args as SitecoreEventArgs;
    Item item = eventArgs.Parameters[0] as Item;
 }
```

"item" returns null. What should I use here to get the item from eventargs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out,

```
SitecoreEventArgs eventArgs = args as SitecoreEventArgs;
Item item = ((Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher)(eventArgs.Parameters[0])).Options.RootItem as Item;//eventArgs.Parameters[0] as Item;
Item existingItem = item.Database.GetItem(item.ID, item.Language, item.Version);
```

This worked!

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer your own question. Next time try to be more specific so we can help better :).

Comment: Hi Yan, "((Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher)(eventArgs.Parameters[0])).Options.RootItem as Item"; code worked instead of "eventArgs.Parameters[0] as Item;" code.